# Open CSV: How to escape comma while exporting SQL dump to CSV

Tags: java, opencsv

I using open CSV to export SQL dump to CSV. In one of the column, I have a lot of commas. After I export into CSV, data in getting split on each comma's. How can I Escape the Comma?

```
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    pst = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Cars");
    rs = pst.executeQuery();

    writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("cars.csv"), 
            DEFAULT_SEPARATOR, NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER);
    writer.writeAll(rs, true);
```

**Actual DATA:**

```
LINESTRING (184317.646019852 55192.7039821837, 184361.902992529 55174.2199648116)
```

**What I'm getting**

```
COLUMN-1                                            COLUMN-2
LINESTRING (184317.646019852 55192.7039821837      184361.902992529 55174.2199648116)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are really want to generate CSV compatible with [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) standard:

```
6.  Fields containing line breaks (CRLF), double quotes, and !!!commas!!!
    should be enclosed in double-quotes.  For example:

     "aaa","b CRLF
     bb","ccc" CRLF
     zzz,yyy,xxx
```

just remove `NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER` option.

Overwise you should find an other library which can generate delimited formats not compatible with CSV (i.e. if you want to use `\` for escape commas instead of double quotes).